# How to get line number in xargs?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, xargs

I want to upload some files to machines in parallel. There's a list of hosts and a list of files that should be uploaded by index: `1.txt` goes to `hostOne`, `2.txt` goes to `hostTwo` etc. Here's what I try to do:

```
cat hosts | xargs -P 10 -I {} scp ./${LINE}.txt user@{}:/tmp
```

How to make it work (`${LINE}` is not a part of xargs syntax)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This filter

```
awk '{print NR ".txt user@" $1 ":/tmp"}'
```

turns `foo` into `1.txt user@foo:/tmp`. The number increases with each line. Your command should be like:

```
<hosts awk '{print NR ".txt user@" $1 ":/tmp"}' | xargs -L 1 scp
```

Adjust it to your needs (e.g. `-P 10`). Also note you don't need `cat` to read the file.

Answer (score 3):

`xargs` can't interpret line numbers for you. Instead you should use something like `nl` to add line numbers:

```
$ echo -ne "a\nb\nc\n" \
    | nl -bt -nln
1       a
2       b
3       c
```

Then, you'll need to format the command so that it can be passed by `xargs` as arguments to `scp`, using something like `sed`:

```
$ echo -ne "a\nb\nc\n" \
    | nl -bt -nln \
    | sed -re 's!^([0-9]+) +\t(.+)$!./\1.txt user@\2:/tmp!'
./1.txt user@a:/tmp
./2.txt user@b:/tmp
./3.txt user@c:/tmp
```

Finally, run!

```
$ echo -ne "a\nb\nc\n" \
    | nl -bt -nln \
    | sed -re 's!^([0-9]+) +\t(.+)$!./\1.txt user@\2:/tmp!' \
    | xargs -P10 -l1 -t scp
scp ./1.txt user@a:/tmp
scp ./2.txt user@b:/tmp
scp ./3.txt user@c:/tmp
```

---

Note that this provides poor association between the host and the file transferred (it's done by line number alone...)

### `nl`

- `-bt` - number only non-empty lines
- `-nln` - use left-justified numbering, with no leading zeroes

### `sed`

- `-r` - use extended regex
- `-e 's!^([0-9]+) +\t(.+)$!./\1.txt user@\2:/tmp!'` - the script to use

  - `^([0-9]+) +\t(.+)$` match numbers followed by spaces, then a tab, then *any character*
  - `\1.txt user@\2:/tmp` - replacements, using groups above (inside `()`)

### `xargs`

- `-P10` - run up to 10 processes concurrently
- `-l1` - limit `xargs` to using one input line per process
- `-t` - print the commands as they are executed

Comment: @nice explanation! Combined with `awk` tip below it looks pretty simple now

Comment: @Poma Formal note: in general there is no "below". The order of answers isn't fixed. You have three options just above all the answers to reorder them for yourself.